# Lua 4 script to convert seconds elapsed to days, hours, minutes, seconds

Tags: time, lua, lua-4.0

I need a Lua 4 script that converts seconds elapsed since `seconds = 0` into a D:HH:MM:SS formatted string. The methods I've looked at try to convert the number to a calendar date and time, but I just need the elapsed time since `0`. It's okay if the day value increments into the hundreds or thousands. How do I write such a script?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is similar to the other answers, but is shorter. The return line uses a format string in to display the result in D:HH:MM:SS format.

```
function disp_time(time)
  local days = floor(time/86400)
  local hours = floor(mod(time, 86400)/3600)
  local minutes = floor(mod(time,3600)/60)
  local seconds = floor(mod(time,60))
  return format("%d:%02d:%02d:%02d",days,hours,minutes,seconds)
end
```

Comment: The game I am working on does not support the `format` function everywhere. But I will mark this answer anyway since I think it is the best.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
function disp_time(time)
  local days = floor(time/86400)
  local remaining = time % 86400
  local hours = floor(remaining/3600)
  remaining = remaining % 3600
  local minutes = floor(remaining/60)
  remaining = remaining % 60
  local seconds = remaining
  if (hours < 10) then
    hours = "0" .. tostring(hours)
  end
  if (minutes < 10) then
    minutes = "0" .. tostring(minutes)
  end
  if (seconds < 10) then
    seconds = "0" .. tostring(seconds)
  end
  answer = tostring(days)..':'..hours..':'..minutes..':'..seconds
  return answer
end

cur_time = os.time()
print(disp_time(cur_time))
```

Comment: `tostring(hours)` should be replaced with `string.sub(100+hours, -2)` or `("0"..hours):sub(-2)`  to make 2-digit string ("HH" format).

Comment: Sorry.  It should be `strsub(100+hours, -2)`

Comment: `math.floor` should be replaced with `floor` for Lua 4

Answer (score 0):

I found an Java example that I was able to adapt.

```
function seconds_to_days_hours_minutes_seconds(total_seconds)
    local time_days     = floor(total_seconds / 86400)
    local time_hours    = floor(mod(total_seconds, 86400) / 3600)
    local time_minutes  = floor(mod(total_seconds, 3600) / 60)
    local time_seconds  = floor(mod(total_seconds, 60))
    if (time_hours < 10) then
        time_hours = "0" .. time_hours
    end
    if (time_minutes < 10) then
        time_minutes = "0" .. time_minutes
    end
    if (time_seconds < 10) then
        time_seconds = "0" .. time_seconds
    end
    return time_days .. ":" .. time_hours .. ":" .. time_minutes .. ":" .. time_seconds
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to create a similar function that has the following characteristics:

- Duration in seconds
- Precision: how many units you want to see (up to 7)
- Delimiter: Default value is space (" ")
- It also calculates centuries
- If a part is zero, it is omitted

The code is the following:

```
function SecToStr(a,b,c) -- Time in seconds, Precision, Delimiter
    local a = math.ceil( math.abs(a) ) or 0
    local b = b or 7
    local c = c or ' '
    if a == math.huge or a == -math.huge then
        return ' ∞ '
    end
    local d = {3153600000,31536000,2592000,86400,3600,60,1}
    local e = {'C','Y','M','D','h','m','s'}
    local g = {}
    for i, v in ipairs(e) do
        local h = math.floor( a / d[i] )
        if h ~= h then
            return table.concat(g, c)
        end
        if b > 0 and ( h > 0 or #g > 0) then
            a = a - h * d[i]
            if h > 0 then
                table.insert(g, h..v)
            end
            b = h==0 and b or b - 1
        end
    end
    return table.concat(g, c)
end
```

I hope it will help.